# I'm having more text inputs text that was supposed

Tags: jquery

I want to select pdfs in my input and after I select pdfs I want to show text inputs.

For example: If I select 2 pdfs to upload I want to show 2 text inputs, because I want to change title of each pdf.

If I select all pdfs that I want at once it is working fine.

But If I select one pdf at a time, I getting always more text inputs that my number of selected pdfs.

For example If I Want to select 2 pdfs, but I select the first and I forgot my second, if this situation happens, after I select my first I´ll select my  second forgotten pdf, but in this case Im getting two text inputs for this second pdf. And I´ll have a total of 3 text inputs for just two pdfs. (So, Im having one text input more)

Do you see why this can be happening?

You can see here my issue demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/j5yeq/4/

This is jQuery script Im using:

```
$('.j_gsendp').click(function(){
$('.j_galleryp').click().change(function () {
    var allFiles = this.files;
    var numFiles = this.files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
    $('.j_gfalsep').animate({
        width: '400'
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).html('You select <strong>' + numFiles + '</strong>files.');
        for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
            var file = allFiles[i],
                name = file.name;
            $('#test').append('<span class="field">Title of pdf ' + name + ':</span><input type="text" name="title[]" value="' + name + '"/><br><br>');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <script>
$('.j_gsendp').click(function(){
$('.j_galleryp').click().change(function () {
    var allFiles = this.files;
    var numFiles = this.files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
    $('.j_gfalsep').animate({
        width: '400'
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).html('You select <strong>' + numFiles + '</strong>files.');
        for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
            var file = allFiles[i],
                name = file.name;
            $('#test').append('<span class="field">Title of pdf ' + name + ':</span><input type="text" name="title[]" value="' + name + '"/><br><br>');
        }


    });
    this.val('');
});
});

</script>
```

I added a this.val(''); This clears the number of files in the input after it has displayed the current count.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SiDix. But with your solution If I want to select two pdfs and I choose just one at first and then I select my second my second replaces my first...

Comment: Are you sure? Once I select another file it just appends it... Here's the jSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j5yeq/7/

Comment: SiDiX Im here with other problem maybe you can help me.This script is working perfectly on google chrome but in internet explorer only works if I select pdfs that are inside my htdocs folder. Do you see what can be wrong?

Comment: It's not allowing you to select files? or it will select the files but not display them?

Comment: I can select files but then... I dont get the file name on my input and I dont get my text input with pdf title!

Comment: Which version of IE? It may not support it.